# Downloading attachment from card at Trello Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, trello

I've got a problem that unables me to download attachment.
Via API I can Upload file as attachment, but instead of authorising via Oauth, I can get attachment, by it's ID, i got accept, but I cannot in response got any answer.

The way I do:

```
response = requests.get(f'https://api.trello.com/1/{card_id}/attachments/{id_of_attachment}', header, allow_redirects=True, auth=self.o_oauth)
```

header is dictionary which is:
empty,
or authorisation,
or authorisation and "fields": url_of_attachment

On every of this questions to Trelo I got access, and 200 Response.  But in response there was no place where I could find my file (I'm uploading this in the same test, and I got accept).

Where, and how should I look for content?

Comment: I manually checked if attachment exist, and is the file, I wanted to upload.